# How can I add sentences from a .txt file to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I am attempting to read a .txt file, separate it by sentences, and create a pandas data frame where each row has one sentence. The output would be:

```
0 "blah blah, blah."
1 "more blah."
2 "more more, blah."
```

My code thus far separates the .txt file by sentences, but I can't seem to figure out how to take each sentence and append it to a pandas dataframe.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import re

with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for l in re.split(r"(\.)",line):
            string += l
        string += '\n'
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv('file.txt')`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Hmm this doesn't create rows with individual sentences, in fact I'm not sure what format it is

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have a loop that returns `string` as a list object of sentences, as in:

```
["blah blah, blah.", "more blah.", "more more, blah."]
```

Then you just need:

```
pd.DataFrame(string)
```

But your loop looks like it would split the sentences on a per line basis, and not across lines. If it is desired to capture sentences across lines then this should do it:

```
string = []    
with open("path/to/file.txt", "r") as f:
    full_text = f.read()
    for l in re.split(r"(\.)", full_text):
        if l != ".":
            string.append(l + "\n")
pd.DataFrame(string)
```